# Проверка включен ли js в браузере у пользователя с условием

Tags: javascript, проверка

Подскажите, нужно проверить включен ли у пользователя js.
Если включен, то вывести одно, если нет вывести изображение.
Проверку на js сделал,а как добавить условия?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("У Вас включён JavaScript!");
</script>
```

Comment: Кто-то отключает JS? Зачем?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513  Пока не столкнулся с такой проблемой, тоже так думал.хДД

Comment: странные юзвери О.о

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ - использовать тег `noscript`.

```
<noscript>
    <img src="картинко.jpg" />
</noscript>
```

Если JS выключен, клиент увидит картинку `картинко.jpg`

Если этот тег разместить в `head`, то можно не только картинку, можно и редирект сделать.